# List pages to show only Whitelisted sub pages

Tags: walker, wp-list-pages

In my custom theme I want to show all parent pages but for a few of those parent pages I don't want to show their subpages.

I know you can add all these subpages to the 'exclude' argument of the wp_list_pages function but I want to make sure that whenever someone adds a new subpage that that one also wouldn't be shown.

Exclude tree could be a possibility but that one also ignores the parent page.

**My code:**

```
$subtitle_walker = new Subtitle_Walker();

$args = array(
    'authors'      => '',
    'child_of'     => 0,
    'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
    'depth'        => 2,
    'echo'         => 1,
    'exclude'      => '',
    'exclude_tree' => '',
    'include'      => '',
    'link_after'   => '',
    'link_before'  => '',
    'post_type'    => 'page',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'show_date'    => '',
    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order',
    'title_li'     => '', 
    'walker'       => new Subtitle_Walker
);

wp_list_pages($args);
```

Comment: So you basically want a _whitelist_ of pages that have subpages attached?

Comment: @kaiser Indeed, all the other pages on the blacklist should not have their subpages shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to whitelist page IDs for `wp_list_pages()` is to use a self removing/single time running filter callback inside `get_pages()`, which is the function retrieving the data from either Cache or from a fresh query to the DB.

You have several options in there:

### Filter the final DB result

To filter the list of returned pages, you can build yourself a quick plugin with a filter callback which you can use in your templates:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: WPSE (#165677) Whitelist pages Callback */
function wpse165677_whitelist_pages( $pages, $arguments )
{
    if ( empty( $pages ) )
        return $pages;

    // Remove instantly
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, 10 );

    // whitelist: loop through pages and build your return array of allowed pages

    return $pages;
}
```

Then, in your template:

```
add_filter( 'get_pages', 'wpse165677_whitelist_pages', 10, 2 );
wp_list_pages( [
    // your arguments
] );
```

This queries some unnecessary pages, but it's a quick solution and might not hurt performance unless you have hundreds of pages.

### Ignore not-whitelisted pages in the MarkUp

Simply build a custom walker that only builds subpage MarkUp for your whitelisted pages.

### Pre fetch and exclude pages

You could do a query for only the ID

```
$wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT id 
    FROM{$wpdb->posts} 
    WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'page' 
        AND {$wpdb->posts}.id IN (%s)",
    join( ",", [ /* IDs Array */ ] ),
);
```

where you then simply diff that return value against all `page` post type returned IDs to build a blacklist. Then return that inside a callback on the `wp_list_pages_excludes`, which is used to fill the `exclude` argument. You can use [`wp_parse_id_list()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_parse_id_list/) to make it easier to build the list.

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_pages_excludes', function( $blacklist )
{
    // logic to build blacklist
    return $blacklist;
}
```

### Pass along arguments

Neither in the docBlock, nor in Codex `wp_list_pages()` is explained that there is no filter running on that functions arguments before they get passed to `get_pages()`. So the `include` argument works on this function as well. Keep in mind that this argument can *not* be used together with `'child_of', 'parent', 'exclude', 'meta_key', 'meta_value', or 'hierarchical'.`

### Conclusion

As often, the task you are facing can get solved using a lot of different ways. What you finally use is up to you and depends on your *very specific* requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive amount of possible solutions. I'd wish to use your plugin solution but I don't know how to correctly implement this with a whitelist. I've also seen that you state a 4th argument in your remove_filter method. What does that '2' do?

Comment: The 4th argument is the number of arguments. It's shouldn't be/doesn't exist on `remove_filter()` and I'll edit the answer.